# Maintaing state in ASP.NET MVC when you're not using the UI helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of forms where its easier to type the entire html tags:

However, when I pass the Model to the View, it doesn't show the value.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Need a little more to go on...

Comment: Yeah it would really help if you post some of your View code here, also are you using BETA or RC1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually inject the values from ViewData.  The helpers encapsulate this, but if you are writing straight HTML there's no way for ASP.NET MVC to know how to wire the values to the form elements.

```
<input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"
       value="<%= ViewData.Model.Name %>" />
```

Comment: I added an example to clarify.

Comment: FYI, as of RC1 you can specify Model.Name (don't need ViewData prefix).

Comment: Yes, you don't need the ViewData "prefix" but it will work both ways.